# Ubuntu 16.04 minimal - extremely slow internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a server on Hetzner that running Ubuntu 16.04 minimal.

The issue is a slow connection to external sources. When I'm trying to `ping` everything looks fine. But when I'm trying to retrieve files from git server (Bitbucket) it takes ages.

The situation gets worse when I'm trying to request using Python Interpreter.
Here are the results:
[image: command results]

When I wrote to support about this issue, they requested `mtr` results so I'm adding those too:[image: mtr]

List of current rules:

```
qdisc mq 0: root 
 Sent 188170970 bytes 419951 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 44) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 44 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :1 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 50287079 bytes 107135 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 8) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 8 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 44682112 bytes 105143 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 13) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 13 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :3 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 47973033 bytes 104060 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 6) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 6 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :4 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 45228746 bytes 103613 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 17) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 17
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem on `Ubuntu 18.04`. My speed test was working fine but when I was installing/updating packages, it was taking very long. Browising was also a problem. [This solution](https://securitronlinux.com/debian-testing/fix-very-slow-internet-on-ubuntu-18-easily) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found the cause of the issue. The slow connection was because of IPv6 configuration. When I disabled IPv6, everything worked fine.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Added these configurations at the end of file:

```
# IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then restarted `sysctl.conf`:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 . How did you find out the issue had to do with IPv6?

Comment: working for me.

Comment: This is frustrating, I implemented the advice here and it hasn't solved the issue. I feel like this is not really helpful since I am still left in the dark about how to diagnose the issue and find the problem.

Comment: YESYESYESYES This worked immediately

Comment: I still have bad network what should I do :,(

Comment: This did not work for me. While my Win7 machine gets 176 Mbps down, while my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS machine gets only 77 Mbps down--still. :(

Comment: Turned my browsing on Lubuntu 18.04 from wheel barrow speed into to a Ferrari

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 20.04 very well.

Comment: ur genius!  Thx!

Comment: This increased my Ethernet connection on Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyana from catastrophically slow (you see web pages build) to pretty Good maybe 5 times faster. I had previously fruitlessly tried a load of other fixes here on Stack*. I 've just back to a webpage where the images never arrived forcing me to try and fix the problem and one refresh and all OK

Comment: worked after I also restarted my network via `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart && sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`