# Why is my internet slower in virtualbox ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu

**Ubuntu 17.04 Minimal**

On my PC I can download at 200kb/s, but in virtual box ubuntu server the max is 10kb/s.

When i installed the O.S it did not take a long time to download files, but with upgrade and update it does.

How can I solve it?

I tried this:

- Bridge and PCNET FAST III - virtual host adapter - NAT
- [Ubuntu 16.04 minimal - extremely slow internet connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366220/ubuntu-16-04-minimal-extremely-slow-internet-connection)
- Change sources.list to us. and archive.ubuntu.com

And nothing get better.

Some extra data:

```
resolv.conf:
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 192.168.1.1

etc/network/interfaces:
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  

# The primary network interface  
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Perhaps try to get a big file of some sort (on HTTP, perhaps), which you can use to reproduce this problem more easily, that is, something that you can use with `wget` or a similar tool to see the current bandwidth. Some `iso` image from a nearby mirror should be enough. Have you tried the *paravirtualized* network adapter in VirtualBox settings? That should give better performance (but still, this does not explain why was it faster during the install).

Comment: @njsg i used all network setting, incluided paravirtualized. i will try using wget